# how to create service for android double tap?

Tags: java, android

Hi i wanted to create a service which detect double tap on home screen i written following code. somehow its not working anyone tell me what is wrong with code

```
public class TapService extends Service implements GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener {

     private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
         gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener()); 
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent arg0) {
        Log.w("Tap", "Double tap");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

my activity class .. i am not getting any error in logcat

```
public class TapActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tap);
        startService(new Intent(this, TapService.class));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.tap, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Not working in what sense. Be more descriptive in your problem definition.

Comment: @Prateek when i come to home screen and do a double tap on screen logcat not showing me my log for double tap, even it is not showing me any error.psb my activity class